Kepler gl Uncaught runtime errors using Draw On Map>Polygon tool and Draw On Map>Rectangle tool:
Kepler gl Uncaught runtime errors using Draw On Map>Polygon tool and Draw On Map>Rectangle tool:
I'm receiving these errors when using the Kepler.gl>Draw On Map>Polygon tool and Draw On Map>Rectangle tool.
Is this possible a redux related item?
**Here's my import for creating the store. **
    ``
    import React from 'react';
    import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
    import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
    import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
    import { thunk } from 'redux-thunk';
    import { taskMiddleware } from 'react-palm/tasks';
    import { keplerGlReducer } from '@kepler.gl/reducers';
    import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
    import './index.css';
    import App from './App';
    ``

    ``
    Uncaught runtime errors:
    ×
    ERROR
    (0 , _rewind.default) is not a function
    TypeError: (0 , _rewind.default) is not a function
        at DrawPolygonMode.rewindPolygon (localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:155146:39)
        at DrawPolygonMode.getAddFeatureAction (localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:155160:32)
        at DrawPolygonMode.getAddFeatureOrBooleanPolygonAction (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:155251:19)
        at DrawPolygonMode.handleClick (localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:153250:31)
        at EditableGeoJsonLayer.onLayerClick (localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:161248:28)
        at EditableGeoJsonLayer._onanyclick (localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:162032:12)
        at EditableGeoJsonLayer._forwardEventToCurrentLayer (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:162022:7)
        at EventRegistrar._emit (localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:344192:9)
        at EventRegistrar.handleEvent (localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:344090:12)
        at Manager.emit (localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:311400:20)
    ``

    ``
    Uncaught runtime errors:
    ×
    ERROR
    (0 , _bboxPolygon.default) is not a function
    TypeError: (0 , _bboxPolygon.default) is not a function
        at DrawRectangleMode.getTwoClickPolygon (localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:199052:51)
        at DrawRectangleMode.getGuides (localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:205182:26)
        at DrawRectangleMode.getTentativeGuide (localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:200606:25)
        at DrawRectangleMode.checkAndFinishPolygon (localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:205147:35)
        at DrawRectangleMode.handleClick (localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:205121:12)
        at EditableGeoJsonLayer.onLayerClick (localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:206738:28)
        at EditableGeoJsonLayer._onanyclick (localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:207522:12)
        at EditableGeoJsonLayer._forwardEventToCurrentLayer (localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:207512:7)
        at EventRegistrar._emit (localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:320708:9)
        at EventRegistrar.handleEvent (localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:320606:12)
    ``

My package.json:
``
{
  "name": "kepler-gl-demo2",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "ajv": "^8.16.0",
    "assert": "^2.1.0",
    "kepler.gl": "^3.0.0",
    "@luma.gl/core": "^8.5.20",
    "@luma.gl/webgl": "^8.5.20",
    "@deck.gl/core": "^8.9.27",
    "@deck.gl/extensions": "^8.9.27",
    "@deck.gl/layers": "^8.9.27",
    "@deck.gl/react": "^8.9.27",
    "@deck.gl/mapbox": "^8.9.27",
    "@nebula.gl/layers": "1.0.2",
    "@nebula.gl/edit-modes": "1.0.2",
    "@nebula.gl/editor": "1.0.2",
    "@nebula.gl/overlays": "1.0.2",
    "@loaders.gl/polyfills": "^4.1.0-alpha.4",
    "react-vis": "^1.11.7",
    "react": "^18.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.3.1",
    "react-palm": "^3.3.8",
    "react-redux": "^9.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "react-virtualized": "^9.22.5",
    "redux": "^5.0.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^3.1.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },

  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
``

To not return the errors when drawing polygons or rectangles.
Expect no errors to return.
